# Create dynamic principal block S3 IAM policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, amazon-iam

I have a terraform module that creates the policy resources that provide different S3 bucket access.

Particularly, the module can be customized using variables to change the bucket, the policy name and more.

```
# part of TF module

[...]

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "read_only" {
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "s3:GetBucketAcl",
      "s3:GetBucketLocation",
      "s3:GetBucketPolicyStatus",
      "s3:GetBucketPublicAccessBlock",
      "s3:GetEncryptionConfiguration",
      "s3:List*",
    ]
    resources = [
      "arn:aws:s3:::${var.s3_bucket_name}"
    ]
  }
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "s3:Get*",
    ]
    resources = [
      "arn:aws:s3:::${var.s3_bucket_name}${var.s3_bucket_prefix}/*"
    ]
  }
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "s3:GetAccountPublicAccessBlock",
    ]
    resources = [
      "*"
    ]
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "read_only_policy" {
  count = var.create_policy_resource ? 1 : 0

  name   = "${var.policy_name_prefix}ReadOnlyPolicy"
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.read_only.json
}
[...]
```

Now the issue is how to provide the capability for roles from other AWS accounts using the `principal` block.

So far I haven't been able to make it work using the [`dynamic` block](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html) as there should be **one and only one** principal block per each statement but only if the variable used to pass the list of principals is not empty.

Any idea of how to tackle this case with Terraform?

Comment: Do you want to allow to assume this role by other AWS accounts, and the list of allowed accounts passed via variable?

Comment: That would be it. Allow other AWS accounts (specified in the principal block) using a terraform variable (list of principals to be allowed to assume the role)